# Foreign Types vs. Unboxed Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

What is the relation between, e.g., `CInt` vs `Int#` vs. `CInt#`?

For example, if I call a foreign function which returns a `CInt`, isn't it already a `CInt#` by construction (i.e., it's a raw `int` on the stack, not a pointer to something on the heap which contains an `int`)?

And in that case, what would be the difference between `CInt` and `Int#`?

If I'm trying to eke out every bit of performance that I can, which one to use out of `CInt` and `Int#` and `CInt#`?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there such a thing as `CInt#`.

- `CInt` is just a custom type which is guaranteed to play well with `C` (see [the blurb at the top of this page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-Types.html) for a more formal take on that). It is boxed, so you take a performance hit for that.
- `Int#` is a "magic" unboxed int. As it turns out, it [does play well with the FFi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#unboxed-types), so use that if you want every bit of performance.